# How to decode output of cardano-cli query ledger-state?

Tags: cardano-cli

Running `cardano-cli query ledger-state --mainnet --out-file out` produces a binary file.
What format is it in?
How can I decode it?
I cannot use the command without `--out-file out` because of memory limitations.

UPDATE

I tried:

```
pip install cbor2
cat ledger-state.cbor | python -m cbor2.tool --pretty > ledger-state.json
```

which gave me:

```
[
    320,
    {
        "\u0000\u0000\u00006\\xd5\u0015\\xe1.\u0018\\xcd<\\x88\\xc7O\t\\xa6y\\x84\\xc2\\xc2y\\xa5)j\\xa9n\\xfe\\x89": 58,
        "\u0000\u0000\u0000\\xf6n(\\xb0\\xf1\\x8a\\xef U_LIT#N2p߻\\xdc\\xc1?T\\xe7\\x99": 57,
[...]
    }
]
```

which does not seem to be decoded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the binary format is [CBOR](https://cbor.io/) and yes, the ledger state is **HUGE**.

I think that if you drop the `--out-file` command line option the output goes to stdout in JSON format but again the output on `mainnet` is so huge that for me `cardano-cli` is killed by the OOM killer on a machine with 16G of RAM.

Using the command you use, the output file is 1.4 Gigabytes (much more compact than the in-memory representation).

There is already a [Github issue](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/issues/2461) about that which is almost a year old.

Comment: Thanks for the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create a readable snapshot of the Cardano ledger as of a given slot, might I suggest using ogmios.dev as a simpler solution.  Ogmios allows one to read the entire state of the ledger via the chain sync mini-protocol.  The ledger is exposed as a websocket api, reducing integration complexity.

Comment: I am planning on using Ogmios but was hoping for a quick and easy way to do a few inspections of the ledger from the commandline with jq.